# iOS app shows notifications when in background but not foreground iphone 4s & os version 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

App is receiving remote notifications when not running state, background state and also get notification in foreground state using local intercept concept(fire local notification when get remote notification). But When app is in foreground and iOS version is 9.3 it does not receives remote notifications.

my code is here:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        {

        NSLog(@"Called");
        NSLog(@"Response - > %@",userInfo);
        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
        localNotification.alertBody = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }

    - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification  withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
    {
        NSLog( @"Handle push from foreground" );
        // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
        NSLog(@"%@", notification.request.content.userInfo);
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
    }

    - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
    {
        NSLog( @"Handle push from background or closed" );
        // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
        NSLog(@"%@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
        NSInteger countNoti = [[[response.notification.request.content.userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];


        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive ) {

            UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
            localNotification.alertBody = [[response.notification.request.content.userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = countNoti;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        }
    }
```

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` called but notification does not show.
Thanks.

Comment: this is not your falut i think .. i have same issue .. i think firebase does not support below 10

Comment: @Mansi When app is in foreground notification does not appear but you will get notifiation on AppDelegate class in DidReceiveNotification Action, here you will handle notification by AlertView.

Comment: yes i know alert view can solve my problem, but i don't want alert view.@AkshayDegada

Comment: I think iOS 9 will not show any notification as iOS 10 when application is in the foreground,

Comment: i think there is no any way to show notification when app is in foreground. may be @DarshitVadodaria is right.

Comment: I think you are not scheduling you Local notification : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; in - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You haven't implemented iOS9 PushNotification Methods in your AppDelegate file

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

**Swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any])
```

You can schedule local notification in above function while app is in the active state. To show notification.